# Convert UTC timestamp to yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS format in hive

Tags: sql, hive, unix-timestamp

I have a scenario like below in hive

convert the current_timestamp to UTC. I am able to do so

```
select to_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp, 'America/Los_Angeles)';
```

Result:

```
2020-02-04 10:00:06.162
```

Next convert this resulting timestamp to `yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS` format.

I have tried like below

```
select from_unixtime((to_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp, 'America/Los_Angeles)', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'), 'yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS');
```

I am unable to get the desired result.

expected result is `20200204100006162`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`date_format`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) function if the Hive version >= 1.2.0.

```
select date_format(to_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp, 'America/Los_Angeles'),'yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS')
```